# Can I provide more permission to a user (Not manager) in Mantis Bug Tracker

Tags: mantis

I'm an administrator of Mantis Bug Tracker in my working place.

There are also several reporter accounts, developer accounts on it.

My question is about both of these user accounts have too less permission.

I'm facing two questions on it,

```
1. Reporter is not able to edit their issues.
2. Developer is not able to create new version number.
```

Is it possible to provide more permission to a user without changing their account type?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unprivileged reporters being able to edit their own issues is not yet possible ( [bug #8141](https://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=8141) ).

Managing versions is tied to `manage_project_threshold`, so if you want your developers to be able to create versions you will need to grant them full access to the project management pages.